# How to implement a custom navigator in React-Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, swipe-gesture

I am trying to implement a custom navigator based on the TabRouter with React Navigation with custom complex animations and behavior, more or less in the fashion of a swipeable CoverFlow.

There are examples out there of how to do that using a StackRouter, but none of them work when changing to a TabRouter.

So far, I have understood that to get a navigator like the TabNavigator I would need a function like:

```
(routeConfigs, config = {}) => (
    createNavigationContainer(
        createNavigator(TabRouter(routeConfigs, config))(MyNavigationView)
    )
);
```

with how to implement `MyNavigationView` being my main interrogation.

The docs are extremely superficial on each component of a navigator, keeping the description to a single sentence most of the time. So, what is precisely, and what is the role of:

- a router
- a navigation view
- the Transitioner (should I use one ?)

Should I (and how) render all the scenes in my `_renderScene` function ?

How do I hide the scenes not displayed at the moment ?

I think I should use a PanResponder from inside the `MyNavigationView` to handle the swipe gesture. Should I (and, if yes, how to) update the router's state when the user swiped to a new scene ?

Also, I do not want to use the `AnimatedTabView` from `react-native-tab-view` that the TabNavigator is using internally as it doesn't work for me on iOS ([conflict between ScrollView and PanResponder which likely won't be fixed for a while](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/521))

That is a lot of questions, but I am a little bit lost. I have been looking a lot at the sources of React Navigation, but they still leave me confused.

Even a partial answer would help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? im having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/CustomTabs.js

So maybe you can update your function like this?

```
createNavigationContainer(
  createNavigator(MyNavigationView, TabRouter(routeConfigs, config), {})
)
```